# Bug in quote found on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707021/c-sharp-override-generic-basemethod-of-other-type) question on Stack Overflow, and noticed the following behavior. The following quote does somehow cut the rest of the sentence:

> 'DoSomeList' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DoSomeList' to 'IDo>'.

`'IDo>'` should be `IDo<System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeType>>`. Check it out in the edit view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `<` with `&lt;` and you're good to go:

> 'DoSomeList<SomeType>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DoSomeList<SomeType>' to 'IDo<System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeType>>'.

The Markdown parser thinks `<` starts an HTML tag, but it's not one of the few actually supported on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Someone has fixed it the same time :)